# How to display the content of my included PHP file on my included HTML file (Ubuntu Server 14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php, lamp

I have created two files: an .php file and a .html file. I am running a LAMP stack on an Ubuntu Server (version 14.04). My .php will pull from an already-composed database on the same server.

My question is: How do I display the content I am fetching from that .php to my .html? How would I write that into the .html?

Thank you!
[Generic Apache Index.html](http://pastebin.com/ZQFxciwA)
[PHP I wish to use](http://pastebin.com/kWHd8af6)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is designed to be embedded into HTML. PHP code begins with a `<?php` tag and ends with a `?>` tag. When the server loads a page, it will run the PHP embedded in the file. Any output that is generated with the `echo` statement becomes part of your HTML. For example, if your PHP code (.php file) was:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello, my name is:
<?php
echo 'John Doe';
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then when you load that page, the PHP echo statement will give you:

```
<html>
  <body>
     Hello, my name is:
     John Doe
  </body>
</html>
```